# How to create ordered list of categories from multiple category groups

Tags: categories, ordering, order, sort

I have got multiple category groups and I need to concatenate them into one list for a filter UI element.

At the moment I have the following:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('colour').all() %}
{% set categories = categories|merge(craft.categories.group('suitability').all()) %}
{% set categories = categories|merge(craft.categories.group('finish').all()) %}
{% set categories = categories|merge(craft.categories.group('shape').all()) %}
{% set categories = categories|merge(craft.categories.group('material').all()) %}
{% set categories = categories|merge(craft.categories.group('edge').all()) %}
{% set categories = categories|merge(craft.categories.group('surface').all()) %}
```

So now I have a list of all the categories within these groups, I can loop over them as follows:

```
<ul class="categories">
    {% for cat in categories %}
        <li class="categories__item">
            <button class="button categories__btn">{{ cat.title }}</button>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But the issue I'm having is that the array of categories is outputting them in the order they're being added. I tried this:

```
{% set categories = categories.orderBy('title asc').all() %}
```

But it returns "Impossible to invoke a method ("orderBy") on an array."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query on multiple category groups like so:

```
craft.categories.group('suitability, finish, shape, material, edge, surface').all()
```

It can also be done with an array:

```
craft.categories.group([
  'suitability',
  'finish',
  'shape',
  'material',
  'edge',
  'surface'
]).all()
```

Whenever you invoke `.all()` it returns an array. As those arrays were merged, they created a larger array. In that last bit of code, `categories.orderBy()` failed because `categories` was an array and arrays do not have a method named `orderBy`.

Hope that helps!